# How to get type of user selected file with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, file

How to get type of file that user  has selected (in some  `<input type="file" name="datafile">`) with jQuery and for example `alert` it? At least its extention but some kind of grouped types like `image` would be grate. Is there any jQuery plugin for that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581308/jquery-or-javascript-get-mime-type-from-url

i dont know, but this may be ur answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function(e){
  var file = $(this).val();
  var ext = file.split('.').pop();
  alert(ext);
});
```

Try this :)

Answer (score 4):

Just provide an id to you input and use this

```
document.getElementById(ID).files[0].type
```

Comment: This isn't supported in IE 9 and lower.  It does work in the IE 10 previews, though.

Comment: `.type` will return Content Type. Example: .xlsx file will return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", not "xlsx"

Answer (score 2):

Try this to get your file extension.

```
var fileName = "Ram.png";
alert(fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

why don't you use something like this:

```
$('input:file').change(function () {
    var ext = this.value.split('.').pop();
    console.log(ext);
});
```

if you want to use a "multiple" field, you can use something like this:

```
$('input:file').change(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ( $this.prop('multiple') ) {
        for ( var i=0; i<this.files.length; i++) { 
            var ext = this.files[i].fileName.split('.').pop();
            // this.files[i].extension = ext;  // usefull for future use
            console.log(ext);
        }
    }
    else {        
        console.log(this.value.split('.').pop());
    }
});
```