# Get MimeType of Image by Javascript in Chrome

Tags: mime-types

For some image elements in a web page, the file extension is not provided. Here is an example.

```
http://c.fsdn.com/allura/p/pdfsam/icon
```

How can I get the image's mimetype by javascript if the file extension is not provided? If possible I am looking for a solution that does not require to get the mimetype detail from Ajax or Network connection. I am looking something like a DOM property:

```
img.mimeType
```

I am try to get the detail for Google Chrome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery or JavaScript: Get MIME Type from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581308/jquery-or-javascript-get-mime-type-from-url)

Comment: No I am not asking for form images. I am asking to get the mimetype of the conventional images in web pages that depict something. Please remove the duplicate warning.

Comment: That question isn't just for form elements. What it says about having to use AJAX is accurate. There is no `mimeType`-like property, except maybe in IE.